# Access field data from entity in block plugin

Tags: 8, entities

I'm attempting to render certain fields within a block plugin but I'm not sure where to start as far as accessing the fields so I can render them.

I'm able to get the node ids after I perform the query using the following code.

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('type', 'blog_post');
    $nids = $query->execute();
```

This retrieves the ids that I need based on the query but I don't know how to access custom fields like blog_summary.

I looked into some functions like getFieldDefinitions(). But I'm not sure how to make use of it. I attempted some things using getStorage but I assumed I wouldn't want to go that route since I'm not attempting to make any changes to the nodes I only want to access their fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function build() {
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'blog_post');
  $nids = $query->execute();

  $build = [];
  foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    $node = Node::load($nid);
    $build[] = $node->blog_summary->view();
  }
  return $build;
}
```

Comment: If you have to load the nodes anyway you can do that immediately via:
'    $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'blog_post']);'

Comment: I'm receiving an error Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\my_plugin\Plugin\Block\Node not found. I thought it might have to do with the namespace but adding use Drupal\Core\Node at the top didn't work, and I already have use Drupal\Core\Entity

Comment: You have to add 
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node; The node entity is provided by the node module of core.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of fields you want to render. For strings and ints you may just use

```
$node = Node::load($nid);
$build[] = $node->field_name->value;
```

Comment: How would I retrieve an image?

Comment: Use the target_id of your entity_reference like this: $node->get('image_field')->target_id. Then load the Image entity with that target_id.

Comment: By target_id do you mean the node id?

Comment: No, the target_id is the entity_id of the image entity that the entity reference field in $node points to.